# loop through elements of array to find character perl

Tags: arrays, perl, scope

I have a perl array where I only want to loop through elements 2-8.

The elements are only meant to contain numbers, so if any of those elements contain a letter, I want to set an `error flag = 1`, as well as some other variables as seen.

The reason I have 2 error flag variables is due to scope rules within the loop.

fields is an array, I created by splitting another irrelevant array by the " " key.

So, when I try to print `error_line2, error_fname2` from outside the loop, I get this:

```
Use of uninitialized value $error_flag2 in numeric eq (==)
```

I don't know why, because I've initialized the value within the loop and created the variable outside the loop. 
Not sure if I'm even looping to find characters correctly, so then it's not setting the `error_flag2 = 1`.

**Example line:**

```
bob hankerman 2039 3232 23 232 645 64x3 324
```

since element 7 has the letter 'x' , I want the flag to be set to 1.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

my $players_file = $ARGV[0];
my @players_array;

open (my $file, "<", "$players_file")
    or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";
while(<$file>) {
    chomp;
    push @players_array, $_;
}
close $file;
#print join "\n", @players_array;

my $num_of_players = @players_array;
my $error_flag;
my $error_line;
my $error_fname;
my $error_lname;

my $error_flag2=1;
my $error_line2;
my $error_fname2;
my $error_lname2;
my $i;
foreach my $player(@players_array){
    my @fields = split " ", $player;
    my $size2 = @fields;    

        for($i=2; $i<9; $i++){
    print "$fields[$i] \n";
            if (grep $_ =~ /^[a-zA-Z]+$/){

                my $errorflag2 = 1;
                $error_flag2 = $errorflag2;
                my $errorline2 = $player +1;
                $error_line2 = $errorline2;
                my $errorfname2 = $fields[0];
                $error_fname2 = $errorfname2;               
            }
        }

    if ($size2 ==  "9" ) {
        my $firstname = $fields[0];
        my $lastname = $fields[1];
        my $batting_average = ($fields[4]+$fields[5]+$fields[6]+$fields[7]) / $fields[3];
        my $slugging = ($fields[4]+($fields[5]*2)+($fields[6]*3)+($fields[7]*4)) / $fields[3];
        my $on_base_percent = ($fields[4]+$fields[5]+$fields[6]+$fields[7] +$fields[8]) / $fields[2];

        print "$firstname ";
        print "$lastname ";
        print "$batting_average ";
        print "$slugging ";
        print "$on_base_percent\n ";
    }
    else {
        my $errorflag = 1;
        $error_flag = $errorflag;
        my $errorline = $player +1;
        $error_line = $errorline;
        my $errorfname = $fields[0];
        $error_fname = $errorfname;
        my $errorlname = $fields[1];
        $error_lname = $errorlname;
    }

}
if ($error_flag == "1"){
        print "\n Line $error_line : ";
    print "$error_fname, ";
        print "$error_lname :";
    print "Line contains not enough data.\n";
}

if ($error_flag2 == "1"){
        print "\n Line $error_line2 : ";
        print "$error_fname2, ";

        print "Line contains bad data.\n";
}
```

Comment: Your use of `grep` is so wrong that this shouldn't compile.

Comment: @zdim so how do i fix it?

Comment: Why not start by showing the code you actually run to get that error? If we work with this we are merely guessing.

Comment: ok i thought my full code might be too confusing but ill add it.

Comment: Thank you, but my point was that `grep` without LIST will not compile. It will not run. You must have `grep BLOCK LIST` or `grep EXPR, LIST` while what you are showing is only `grep EXPR`. I don't see how that code can print anything other than `Not enough arguments for grep ...` -- and not run at all.

Comment: Is there another way without using grep? I was playing around with if statements before, but my issue is that i have no clue how to really loop through elements of an array to check for stuff Ike that without splitting it into another array .

Comment: I suggest to check what you have that runs and prints the error you show.  As for the basics of what you are asking, `if (grep { /[a-z]/i } @fields[2..9]) { ... }`

Comment: Also, `for ($i=2, ...)` is not a good way to loop over a range of numbers; you would normally do `for my $i (2..9)` but that's most likely not needed here. I suggest a good tutorial on Perl, and for this question to fix it and someone might offer a review of basics.

Comment: Re "*ok i thought my full code might be too confusing but ill add it.*", No, that's backwards!!! You should post the minimal, runnable code that demonstrates your problem. (See [mcve].)

Comment: Re "_how to really loop through elements of an array_" -- if you use `grep` you don't need to; it process a list (in the way I showed above). This does assume that I understand what you need (to find whether any of elements 2--9 of array `@fields` contains a letter).

Answer (score 5):

OK, so the problem you've got here is that you're thinking of `grep` in Unix terms  - a text based thing. It doesn't work like that in perl - it operates on a list.

Fortunately, this is pretty easy to handle in your case, because you can `split` your line into words.

Without your source data, this is hopefully a proof of concept:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;


while ( <DATA> ) { 

   #split the current line on whitespace into an array. 
   #first two elements  get assigned to firstname lastname, and then the rest  
   #goes into @values
   my ( $firstname, $lastname, @values ) = split; #works on $_ implicitly.
   #check every element in @values, and test the regex 'non-digit' against it. 
   my @errors = grep { /\D/ } @values;
   #output any matches e.g. things that contained 'non-digits' anywhere. 
   print Dumper \@errors; 

   #an array in a scalar context evaluates as the number of elements. 
   #we need to use "scalar" here because print accepts list arguments. 
   print "There were ", scalar @errors, " errors\n";

}

__DATA__
bob hankerman 2039 3232 23 232 645 64x3 324
```

Or reducing down the logic:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) { 
   #note - we don't need to explicity specify 'scalar' here,
   #because assigning it to a scalar does that automatically. 

   #(split) splits the current line, and [2..8] skips the first two. 
   my $count_of_errors = grep { /\D/ } (split)[2..8];       
   print $count_of_errors;
}

__DATA__
bob hankerman 2039 3232 23 232 645 64x3 324
```

Answer (score 0):

First : You don't need to use "GREP", Simply you can match the string with "=~" in perl and you can print matched value with $&.

Second : You should use $_ if and only if there is not other variable used in the loop. There is already $i used in the loop, you can write the loop as :

```
for my $i (2..9) {
  print "$i\n";
}
```

or

```
foreach(2..9) {
  print "$_\n";
}
```